# How I can parse Pipeline sign from string in xslt

Tags: xslt

How I can parse pipeline sign from fields in xslt. e.g.

dummy1|dummy2|dummy3|dummy4

Regards,
Sarah

Answer (score 3):

If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor you can use the `tokenize` function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) e.g. with an input of

```
<foo>dummy1|dummy2|dummy3|dummy4</foo>
```

you can match

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to output `dummy1 dummy2 dummy3 dummy4`. If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor you can check whether it supports an extension function like http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/ or you need to write a recursive, named template splitting up the input.

Answer (score 1):

In xlst 1.0 I usually use recursive call of named template, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dummyVar" select="'dummy1|dummy2|dummy3|dummy4'" />
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dummies>
            <xsl:call-template name="parseDummy">
                <xsl:with-param name="parsedString" select="$dummyVar" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </dummies>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="parseDummy">
        <xsl:param name="parsedString" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($parsedString, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before($parsedString, $delimiter)}" />
                <xsl:call-template name="parseDummy">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parsedString" select="substring-after($parsedString, $delimiter)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{$parsedString}" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's on you what you need to do with parsed values, in example I construct elements with names of dummies.

Be careful about context which is changing.

Comment: Hi Jirka,I need this format I am unable to understand how I can get values in these field. check this <dummy1>SCB MAIN</dummy1> <dummy2>123111233097812312301</dummy2> <dummy3>Main Branch</dummy3>

Comment: Provide pls input xml - I don't know where values like SCB MAIN comes from.

Comment: <m:WorkerABO>
<m:WorkerABOList>
<m:Dummy>Standard Chartered|SCBMAIN|24 1130978 01|Main Branch|7343347788899||215343271787|Test_TestXXYY</m:Dummy>
</m:WorkerABO>
</m:WorkerABOList>

and need these values after parsing in these fields
<m:Dummy2>NULL</m:Dummy2>
<m:Dummy3>NULL</m:Dummy3>
<m:Dummy4>NULL</m:Dummy4>
<m:Dummy5>NULL</m:Dummy5>

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not able to see any logic in previous example (even it is not well formed). What is a relation between input `<m:Dummy>` and output `<m:Dummy2-5>`?