# How I can do it in XSLT parse one dummy values with "_" saparated

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have one field and I need to parse with "_" and put in different fields mentioned below.
Can you please tell me how I can do it in xslt.

```
<ws:Field name="dummy1">Standard Chartered_SCB_MAIN_24 1130978 01_Main Branch_77788899__215271787_Test_TestXXYY</ws:Field>
```

Bank Name                     : Standard Chartered

Bracnh Code/ID                : SCB MAIN

Account Number                : 123111233097812312301

Branch Name                   : Main Branch

Bank Identification Code      : 1113781813213899

IBAN                          :

Bank Code/ID                  : 1231231787

Name of Account               : Test

Account Nickname              : TestXXYY

Regards,
Sarah

Comment: You can make use of `tokenize(string, '_')` in XSLT 2.0. But you have underscores both as separators and as part of the BranchCode/ID value (`SCB_MAIN`). Does BranchCode/ID always contain a single underscore?

Comment: Be careful not to post Personally Identifiable Information online. You can get in big trouble!!! Make sure to scramble those numbers as much as possible.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks but its fake number not the real one :P

Comment: Hi Alex, But how I can put values in different field of bankdetail can you please give me example for that thanks in advance :)

Comment: In xslt 1.0 you can use recursive call of templates (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534646/1324394)

Comment: no I need this format like 
<dummy1>SCB MAIN</dummy1> 
<dummy2>123111233097812312301</dummy2> 
<dummy3>Main Branch</dummy3> etc..

Answer (score 0):

Look into `tokenize` or perhaps better `xsl:analyze-string`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regex-examples for examples. You would need to have a clear specification of the pattern of the possible input strings, then it is easy to write a regular expression pattern that matches the stuff you are looking for and processes the matched items (e.g. wraps them into result elements).